# Recall last opened file using a sandbox application on OSX

Tags: qt, appstore-sandbox

I'm submitting my application written using C++ *Qt* framework and I choose to use sandboxing.

Before sandboxing, my application was able to recall the last opened file stored in the settings. Now I have the following error in the *Console*:

```
sandboxd[31386]: ([35064]) Joker(35064) deny file-read-data /Users/martin/Dropbox/DirtyLove/DirtyLove.detx
```

How can I perform this behavior in the sandboxed world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prompt the user to open the file through the standard Open File dialog. This is a common requirement of the sandboxing logic. You can't be reading user's data without explicit permission.

Comment: So what is the functional alternative for this behaviour?

Comment: @MartinDelille Are you asking if there is a way to bypass that in a sandbox? No, there's no way. That's the purpose of the sandbox: a rogue application shouldn't be able to snoop on user's data and, say, ship user's files off to a remote site.

Comment: No that no what I'm asking. I mean how can we recall the last file automatically like GarageBand do for example?

Comment: @MartinDelille Sorry, I was wrong. It seems that sandboxing explicitly [allows](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html) opening recent files. Read that link - I presume the issue is that recently opened files must appear in the menu, and must perhaps be added to the menu using native APIs. [This project](http://members.shaw.ca/akochoi/articles/Qt-document-based-application/) demonstrates the techniques, I believe.